# Why getting Undefined value when i compare my input value to csv column

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, promise, async-await

I have a problem and I'm sure lot of you can resolve it, my goal is to compare my input value to CSV column, and later on, if the comparison is true, the chart will be traced. However I'm struggling with this part, every time I `console.log` my input values, it says its `undefined`.
I'm sure it's a problem related to promises, but I can't find a valid solution.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const selectedFile = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
  d3.csv(selectedFile.name)
    .then(function(players, data) {
      var y = document.getElementById("yLabel").value;
      var x = document.getElementById("xLabel").value;
      document.getElementById("y_one").innerHTML = y;
      document.getElementById("x_one").innerHTML = x; // HERE X OR Y ARE DEFINED
      console.log("take this value " + x);
      const playerLabels = players.map(function(d) {

        console.log(x); //HOWEVER IN THIS PART , IT SAYS IS UNDEFINED
        return d.x;
      });
      console.log(playerLabels);

      const weekData = players.map(function(d) {
        console.log("lol");
        return d.Weeks;
      });

      var chart = new Chart("chart", {
        type: "horizontalBar",
        options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        data: {
          labels: playerLabels,
          datasets: [{
            data: weekData,
          }, ],
        },
      });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p>
  Please enter x axis and y axis correctly, else you wouldnt get correct graph
</p>
x labels :
<input type="text" id="xLabel" /> y labels :
<input type="text" id="yLabel" />
<input type="file" id="myFile" multiple size="50" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate graph</button>

<p id="y_one"></p>
<p id="x_one"></p>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: If I replace your file with any other CSV file, I do get the input value of `x` printed, so it's probably related to your input file, or you didn't read the output correctly. I used [this file](https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/d6774e9422bd72369f195a30d3a6b33ff9d41676cff4d89c93511e1a458efb3cfd16cbb7ce3fecdd8dd2466121e10c9bfe57fd73c7520bf358d352a92b898614?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename*%3DUTF-8%27%27energy.csv), from an online example

Comment: It shld display an array of values, i got an array of undefined values, did you get the same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I replace your file with any other CSV file, I do get the input value of `x` printed - but from your comments it sounds like you're actually looking for the column with the input name of `x`.

In that case, use `d[x]`, not `d.x`. The former *evaluates* the variable x and gets the column whose name matches its value. The latter doesn't evaluate and gets the column with name "x".

In the following example, correct values are "source', "target", and "value", and they don't give an array of undefined values!

```js
function myFunction() {
  const selectedFile = "https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/d6774e9422bd72369f195a30d3a6b33ff9d41676cff4d89c93511e1a458efb3cfd16cbb7ce3fecdd8dd2466121e10c9bfe57fd73c7520bf358d352a92b898614?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename*%3DUTF-8%27%27energy.csv";
  d3.csv(selectedFile)
    .then(function(players, data) {
      var y = document.getElementById("yLabel").value;
      var x = document.getElementById("xLabel").value;
      document.getElementById("y_one").innerHTML = y;
      document.getElementById("x_one").innerHTML = x;
      console.log("take this value " + x);
      const playerLabels = players.map(function(d) {
        return d[x];
      });
      console.log(playerLabels);

      const weekData = players.map(function(d) {
        return d.Weeks;
      });

      var chart = new Chart("chart", {
        type: "horizontalBar",
        options: {
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
        },
        data: {
          labels: playerLabels,
          datasets: [{
            data: weekData,
          }, ],
        },
      });
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p>
  Please enter x axis and y axis correctly, else you wouldnt get correct graph
</p>
x labels :
<input type="text" id="xLabel" value="source" /> y labels :
<input type="text" id="yLabel" />
<button onclick="myFunction()">Generate graph</button>

<p id="y_one"></p>
<p id="x_one"></p>

<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```